# how to upload file with title and description using vuex and laravel

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, laravel-8

i have a section in my project where i can upload a post with image

i tried this but it's returning a 419 status

vue script:

```
    <script>
export default {
    data() {
        return{
            post: {
                title: '',
                description: '',
            },
            file: '',
            name: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(e){
            this.file = e.target.files[0];
        },

        createPost(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            }

            let data = new FormData();
            data.append('file', this.file);

            this.$store.dispatch('createPost', this.post, data, config);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

vuex store's actions:

```
createPost({}, post, data, config){
        axios.post('api/createPost',{
            title: post.title,
            description: post.description
        }, data , config ).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
```

i'm gettinh this error:

POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/api/createPost 419 (unknown status)

Comment: Missing the CSRF token? Do you add/send it somewhere?

Comment: i thought i only need csrf token when using blade, and i'm using vue for the front-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out

the script should've been like this :

```
    <script>
export default {
    data() {
        return{
            post: {
                title: '',
                description: '',
            },
            file: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(e){
            this.file = e.target.files[0];
        },

        createPost(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            }

            let data = new FormData();
            data.append('file', this.file);
            data.append('title', this.post.title);
            data.append('description', this.post.description);

            this.$store.dispatch('createPost', data, config);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and the vuex file should've containe this :

```
createPost({}, data, config){
        axios.post('/api/createPost', data , config ).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.error(err);
        })
    }
```